# How do I print out the results of my delete script in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find a way to get my script to print out a log file of what files are actually being deleted. Does anyone know how I could go about doing this? Here is my screen I would like to add that onto.

```
Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) } |
    Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: It's likely that you may only need to add the -Verbose parameter to the Remove-Item cmdlet. The verbose statement will indicate that that the remove file operation is being performed against a file to include its full path.

Comment: Before you run that command, you can also add a quick `-whatif` to the end of your remove item.  It'll print out what it will do without actually removing the files.  It's saved my bacon more than a few times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall easiest way if you just need a log would be to use a `Transcript` and Verbose Output.

your script would look like this, make sure you pay attention to the addition of `-Verbose` to your command.

```
Start-Transcript C:\Logs\Remove.txt
Some-Command | Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) } | Remove-Item -Force -Verbose
Stop-Transcript
```

then the `C:\Logs\Remove.txt` file will have a message like this for each removed file:

```
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "H:\dns.csv".
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the `Remove-Item` cmdlet doesn't support the `-Passthru` parameter, which might make this easier.  However, you could do this:

```
Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) } |
Tee-Object -FilePath .\Log.txt |
Remove-Item -Force
```

But that's a bit ugly because it outputs the directory listing from `Get-ChildItem`.  You could do this instead to capture just the paths:

```
Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) } |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName |
Tee-Object -FilePath .\Log.txt |
Remove-Item -Force
```

Also, note that if you're using PowerShell v3.0 or later, the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet supports the `-File` and `-Directory` parameters, so you don't need to do the whole `-not $_.PsIsContainer` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a loop:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Targets |
    Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) } |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_ | Remove-Item -Force
        $_.FullName | Out-File -FilePath $LogFile -Append
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to write output to log file is by using -Verbose and then use Write-Verbose or 4> after the command

```
Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) } | Remove-Item -Verbose 4> $log_file_path
```